# How does variable binding actually work in groovysh?

Tags: variables, binding, groovy, groovyshell

Here's the crux of what I don't understand:

```
% groovysh
Groovy Shell (1.8.6, JVM: 1.6.0_21)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> class vars {
groovy:001> static int x = 1;
groovy:002> }
===> true
groovy:000> println new vars().x
1
===> null
groovy:000> println vars.x
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
No such property: vars for class: groovysh_evaluate
Possible solutions: class
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
```

If `vars` resolves to something in the expression `new vars().x`, why not also in the expression `vars.x`? It's like a phantom identifier that only actually exists for purposes of instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are using the wrong naming conventions. You should write the class with a capital V. This way the Groovy shell knows you are referring to a class, instead of a variable, in case the Groovy cannot determine it.

This is what you really want:

```
groovy:000> class Vars {
groovy:001>     static int x = 1
groovy:002> }
===> true
groovy:000> Vars.x
===> 1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! Sounds like an epic hack/heuristic in the implementation of groovysh. Interestingly `new vars()` works just fine.

Comment: Follow up: is there documentation somewhere of all the rules like this that groovysh uses for resolving names to classes/variables/etc.?

Comment: Of course 'new vars' works just fine, see below for my explanation. What would work btw is 'myVars = new vars()'. That does create a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `vars` is a *class*, not an object, and x is not declared as a static property.  The best practice is to always name your classes with an upper case letter to prevent this kind of confusion.

Comment: Lol, actually `x` is static. And case is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is downvoted, since it's (mostly) the correct answer, except for the static part. The variable 'vars', which you are referring to, doesn't exist. There is no variable named vars, only a class, hence the error message: 'no such property'

Comment: Thanks.  I *did* misread the question, though, and am suitably chastened.

Comment: Sorry, @BigEd, it was indeed the lowercase, though your answer made it sound like it was a matter of style rather than actual groovysh "syntax". I'll undo my downvote as soon as the lock lifts.

Comment: @ErikPragt, I'm not sure it's quite true that there is _no_ variable `vars`; after all `new vars()` works. I would instead say that `vars` is a variable (i.e., a name) that names (i.e., is bound to, resolves to, refers to) a class. Or at least, that's what I was expecting; but apparently groovysh depends on certain case-sensitive naming conventions to help it figure out what exactly a given name refers to, which I was violating here.

Comment: Hi Maxy-B, I'm very sure there is no variable vars. The 'new vars()' doesn't create a variable, but a new object. You might be confused because you mixed up upper/lower casing). Saying 'vars' is a variable is wrong. This has nothing to do with groovysh btw, also without groovysh 'new vars' still wouldn't be a variable.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit sloppy with the term "variable". I mean a "name", a "token", a sequence of characters in the programming language that can refer to something. The code `class vars {...}` creates a name `vars` in some namespace, which refers to a class; you use that name when you instantiate the class with `new vars()`; what's confusing in Groovy is that it fails when you try to use that same name to refer to its static member.

Comment: Since everything in Groovy is an object, vars would be an object which is an instance of java.lang.Class.